# Number of staked tokens

Tags: staking

I'm thinking which events/calls (or whatever) should I take into account to get a number of staked in the protocol? I did this exercise for Reef protocol (but this should be similar for all Substrate protocols) based on 'Staking.Bonded' and 'Staking.Withdrawn' events, but my number does not match with a presented on [the reef protocol subscan - 6.2B](https://reef.subscan.io/validator) . I would like to be able to calculate this metric on a wallet level in the future incl. historical values that's why I'm trying to do it based on events.

In other words, which events are responsible for increasing a number of staked tokens and which ones decrease this value?

Answer (score 2):

When a nominator has chosen the reward destination as `Staked` ([see here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/lib.rs#L400)), when staking rewards are paid out, it increases the nominator stake without a `Bonded` event. Refer [code note here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L699) and the [payout code here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L293). This is the value you might be missing. There is no easy way to take it into account with just reading events.

I believe the best way to do this is to add on every `Rewarded` event, the rewarded amount if the nominator has set their reward destination `Staked` which you can know by reading the `Payee` [storage item](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L327).